# DHCP server providing two IP addresses to the same Host

Tags: linux, routes, dhcp

I have two subnets (A and B) in the same local area network where all IP addresses are static. I just created a DHCP server to solve the problem of IP address conflict.

The problem that there are Hosts that must belong to both Subnets and therefore have two IP addresses.

The router solution is not accepted because if a subnet A station wants to access a station in network B, it must go through the router, but the traffic is very important (SQL queries for statistics) which can cause the flood of the router.

Short: Can I configure my DHCP server to provide two IP addresses to the same Host?

Server operating system: Linux Suse (DHCPD)

Comment: Please write your question in English.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a DHCP problem, it's a routing problem. 
AFAICT DHCP only lets you specify one IP address per client, but it also lets you push static routes.

You do not need your client to have an IP on both networks, you just need it to know which route to use to reach peers on network A and B (ie direct route in both cases).

See https://gauvain.pocentek.net/docs/dhcpd-push-routes/ to specify static routes for DHCP.